# WCF service endpoints are not recognized by azure service bus after any change in web.config file or iis reset

Tags: wcf, azure

I am trying to expose the WCF Service endpoints using azure service bus.
when i publish the service on IIS service, these end points are not getting recognized.
but after I publish, when i click on browse and open the .svc file.
then I am able to see the endpoints in Azure service bus.
Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Until your service is actually started (i.e. when you browse to the .svc file), the Service Bus Listener can't be activated.  You need to add an AutoStart class that implements System.Web.Hosting.IProcessHostPreloadClient with a PreLoad method.  There is a full example at [Hosting WCF Services with Service Bus Endpoints on IIS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh966775.aspx).

Comment: i will do this and check